# Select columns whose name is not present in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, dynamic-sql

Is there a way to only select the columns whose names are not present on another table? For example

```
Table A                         Column B
ID  | Name   | Address          Address
-----------------------
1   | Daniel | dummy
```

In this example my select statement should be like this:

```
select ID, Name from Column A
```

I've seen people talking about dynamic SQL but I can't find a decent example to solve my issue, any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need this?

Comment: Column B is a configuration column. I'm dealing with massive file export systems and the user is allowed to insert columns to be excluded from the file. Hence the need to dynamically read only the desired columns from table A (those who were not excluded by the user). Unfortunately I can't make a filter on the file export system since that is already set in stone.

Comment: You still haven't tagged with your database.  We can't read your mind.

Comment: My bad, edited.

Comment: Are `Column A` and `Column B` columns or tables? Are `ID`, `Name`, `Address` values or columns?

Comment: Edited to make it more clear. Id, Name and Address are columns in Table A whilst ColumnB is a column from another table and 'Address' is a value from ColumnB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a version of the way you would do this using dynamic SQL:

```
declare @cols varchar(max);
set @cols = NULL;

select @cols = coalesce(@cols + ', ' + column_name, column_name)
from information_schema.columns ca 
where ca.table_name = 'A' and
      ca.column_name not in (select cb.column_name
                             from information_schema.columns cb
                             where cb.table_name = 'B'
                            );

declare @sql varchar(max);
set @sql = 'select [cols] from A';
set @sql = replace(@sql, '[cols]', @cols);

exec sp_executesql @sql;
```

This is a bit simplified to show how the `information_schema` tables can be sued.  It will work in many circumstances, but is not maximally general:

- It doesn't take schema name into account.
- It assumes all names are simple ASCII.
- It does not escape the column names (assuming the names do not need to be escaped).

Answer (score -1):

Select the other table in the `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT ID, NAME
FROM ColumnA
WHERE NAME NOT IN (SELECT NAME FROM COLUMNB)
```

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP wants.  I think the OP wants to select the `ID` and `NAME` columns, excluding `ADDRESS`, because `ADDRESS` appears in the other table.

Comment: I think you missunderstood me, my desired result is how @TimBiegeleisen explained.